# jQuery: How can I filter through an array, skipping some key:value pairs?

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, filter

I'm trying to write a little validation plugin and have all my classes that are being applied to elements upon pass, failure, active or passive state in a jQuery array like so:

```
classes : {
    active      : "active",
    passive     : "passive",
    error       : "error",
    passed      : "passed",
    placeholder : "placeholder"
}
```

I would now like to create a comma separated list of the values of these keys **excluding** `[active]` & `[passive]` from this list.

So that it would give me (based on the above array):

```
"error,passed,placeholder"
```

How can I filter out some `key:value` pairs before writing this string to my variable?

Thanks,
Jannis

Comment: How do you write the string values into a variable *right now*? You're question implies you already have some code. Show it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using jquery MAP method:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

or simply iterate through the array

```
var returnArray = '';
$.each(class, function(key, value){
   if(value == 'active' || value == 'passive'){
      returnArray += value;
   }
});
```